# Will the http request be made if delegate is nil in NSURLConnection's connectionWithRequest:delegate:?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

In my app I need to call a http url for tracking purposes. I'm not interested in the response at all. Will the web servers code be invoked, i.e.  will the request be made, if I set do a asynchronous request with:

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:trackingUrl];
NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:nil];
```

Comment: I didn't had the infrastructure when I asked, but now I did (answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested myself and the request is done and the response seems to be consumed somewhere in the depth of `NSURLConnection` and sent to the `nil`-delegate.